# Что делает инструкция VOLUME в Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Никак не могу понять что делает инструкция `VOLUME ["/data"]` в Dockerfile, сначала я думал, что это аналог опции `-v` и что можно написать так: `VOLUME ["С:/test:/data"]`, но оказался не прав. Так что за директорию создает иснтрукция `VOLUME` и где она хранится на хост-машине (windows)? И как лучше и правильно подключать директорию с данными, например, БД к контейнеру? Через опцию `-v`?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, не помогло, можно как то своими словами?

Answer (score 6):

VOLUME говорит о том, что при запуске контейнера необходимо создать директорию на хосте, заполненную данными из образа, и смонтировать в указанной точке внутри контейнера (/data):

- Контейнер стартует
- Перед стартом в дебрях инсталяции докера создается пустая директория
- В директорию копируется содержимое /data из образа
- Директория монтируется в контейнер по пути /data

Хранится она где-то внутри установки Docker (где именно это на Windows - не знаю). Не побоюсь собственного оценочного суждения - это абсолютно бесполезная директива, которая несет [больше вреда](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/255), нежели пользы (потому что, например, она остается жить после смерти контейнера, потребляя ненужное место, и обнаружить в какой-то момент тысячи ненужных volume - это обычное дело). Если вам необходимо вынести данные из контейнера для сохранения (например, чтобы сохранить БД между запусками контейнера), то действительно лучше использовать `-v`. Основная разница между `-v` и `VOLUME` в Dockerfile состоит в том, что в `-v` вы указываете конечную директорию, которую нужно пробросить внутрь контейнера и сами управляете ей, а VOLUME проделывает почти то же самое, только эта директория находится непонятно где, управляется самим докером (обычно наоборот, вовсе не управляется), и управление всем этим добром стоит порядочного количества нервов.

Comment: Путь монтирования на хосте(при использовании VOLUME) можно узнать с помощью docker inspect --format="{{.Volumes}}"

Answer (score 2):

`VOLUME` может быть очень полезен, когда в процессе сборки контейнера запускается некоторый процесс, который заполняет папку начальным набором файлов (инициализирует). Например, это может быть папка базы данных.
Далее, в `docker-compose.yaml` или в `docker run` `docker volume create` вы создаете вульюм и в нем уже будут файлы, которые были помещены в папку, указанную в декларации `VOLUME`, непосредственно до этой самой декларации.

Т.е. `VOLUME` - значит взять содержимое папки (внутри контейнера) и поместить его в вульюм, который прикрепить к итоговому образу.

Важно понимать, что использование при запуске Docker-образа *папки в качестве вульюма* - это скорее костыль (хак, трюк). В этом случае содержимое вульюма из образа не будет развернуто. Используйте команды

```
Usage:  docker volume COMMAND

Manage volumes

Options:
      --help   Print usage

Commands:
  create      Create a volume
  inspect     Display detailed information on one or more volumes
  ls          List volumes
  prune       Remove all unused volumes
  rm          Remove one or more volumes
```

Comment: данные в папке и так сохранятся в образ без volume.

Answer (score 0):

Если все еще актуально.
В папке C:\Users\YourProfileName\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data есть файл с образом виртуального тома ext4.vhdx. Там и хранятся. В линуксе должно быть тоже самое, за исключением пути. Но не проверял.