# Проброс файлов СУБД в файловую систему в докере

Tags: linux, база-данных, docker, rethinkdb

Есть задача: запустить БД `RethinkDB` в докере. Проблема в том, что при остановке контейнера все данные таблиц пропадают. Я нагуглил, что можно сделать проброс файлов БД в файловую систему линукс. Как можно это сделать? Есть мануал?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779092/178576

Answer (score 1):

Документация находится по ключевым словам docker volume, а еще пример запуска RethinkDB в докер контейнере есть на docker-hub в инструкции по использованию образа с одноименной базой. Если ты используешь образ с базой из docker-hub то там в Dockerfile есть такая сточка

```
VOLUME ["/data"]
```

что должно подсказать где находятся файлы данных. Тебе нужно смонтировать эту директорию из контейнера в подходящую директорию на хосте, посредством команды *-v <путь_на_хосте>:/data*. Пример:

```
docker run -v "$PWD:/data" -d rethinkdb
```

Здесь $PWD заменится интерпретатором командой строки на директорию в который ты исполнишь команду, лучше укажи абсолютный пусть в заранее созданную папку.